# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib3' even if installed

Tags: python, module, pip

I am a beginner and I am trying to run this [github code](https://github.com/kimdoanh89/sdwan-python-rest-api) using virtual environment on windows 10:
py -3
When executing I get error:

```
$ py -3 sdwancli.py --help

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib3'`
```

However I have urllib3 installed -

```
$ pip3 list
Package           Version
----------------- ---------
urllib3           1.26.2
```

Some other outputs:
$ which python
/c/Users/XXX/vmanage/kim/sdwan-python-rest-api/vmanage/\Users\XXX\vmanage\kim\kim/Scripts/python

Order of operation on the image below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/022f6.png)

Comment: To make sure that I'm using the pip I want, I always do, e.g., `py -3 -m pip list`